# How to fix mismatch input x expecting y

Tags: character, antlr, lexer

I am new to antler and creating a parse tree. I am trying to create tokens that include a special character, but when I do so it gives me an input mismatch.

I have tried to add a special character to my LEXER rules by adding a '.' at the end, however when I do so it give me the error of input mismatch. The snippet of code that I am trying will work on its own but not as part of the entire code.

This is the code I have so far...

```
grammar Grammar4;
r : WORD', 'NUMBER', 'BOOL', 'SENT+;

BOOL : 'true' | 'false';

WORD : [a-zA-Z]+;

NUMBER : [0-9]+;

SENT : [a-zA-Z ]+;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

If I add a period at the end of SENT to allow for special characters ([a-zA-Z ]+.;) then I get an input mismatch. If I take that line out and use it independently of the rest than I can have a sentence like, "How are you today!" and have it tokenize fine.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edited for clarity:
I am trying to parse a statement like, Alex, 31, false, I let the dog out! (note that I can get everything to parse as an individual token except the last special character and I would like "I let the dog out!" to be one token.

Comment: Can you show an example of the input you try to parse?

Comment: Tim, 31, false, I let the dog out!

Comment: I guess you want something like `SENT : ([a-zA-Z ] | '!')+;`. You should specify explicitly which characters a token may consist of. If you simply write something like `.*`, there will be no way for the lexer to find out, say, what `Tim` is. Since it can match both: `WORD` and `SENT`. However, if you really need a rule "any character accepted after <some condition>" I'd suggest looking at [Lexical modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have everything working perfectly now!